# HTML5 date input width

Tags: html

So i am having an issue trying to force a size on a date input. Has anyone else had this issue or know how to get around it?

```
<input style="width:50px;" type="date" value="">
```

It is pretty simple, the width only changes the textarea, the actual control does not change, it is fixed at about 125 px width or so.

I have also tried width="" and max-width in the css, neither work.

Comment: You want the mm/dd/yyyy to expand as well or the control seems to expand for me. I might be understanding wrong though.   http://jsfiddle.net/supplement/xu9Xm/

Comment: Notice my example uses 50px, not 250? I want to go smaller than the default, not larger. Thanks.

Comment: i understand what you're saying now... that's a good question.  I'll see if i can dig anything up for you my friend.

Comment: This is probably not what you want to hear, but you might want to scrap it.. it works nicely in chrome but doesn't even work in FF.

Comment: I have the same issue on Android, did you find a solution?

Comment: Honestly i have not messed with Android in awhile. However you can adjust the width in Chrome now, so i would imagine it will be available to Android soon as it also uses Webkit.

Answer (score 8):

With chrome 45, I just set the font-size.  It proportionately changed the text and the control handles.  Not sure that was the effect you were looking for(?).

```
<input style="font-size: 3rem"  type="date" id="Date">
```

Comment: @AustinBest Then selecting an answer as "solution" would be the appropriate action to take.

Comment: Far from trolling. Answering your own question with _wontfix_ would be a valid answer as well.

Comment: Since this was at the top of my google search, and now that it is 2017, I was able to squeeze Chrome down to width: 10em;, but that's as small as I could get it (and that isn't much smaller than the default).  I like this answer better then the others.

Answer (score 6):

An `<input type=date>` element is supposed to be implemented in a browser-dependent manner that is suitable for the environment where the browser is running. So it is supposed to be under the browser’s control, not an author’s. This is one reason why many people are skeptical about the idea.

Setting a width for the control is really a shot in the dark. On my Chrome (25beta on Win 7), your CSS code “works” in the sense of truncating the widget to the given width. It still works, but it looks very odd: in the widget, the letter “v” and part of some other letter is visible. They are really the notation “vvvv-kk-pp” (localized notation for “yyyy-mm-dd”), which I can see in the widget in the absence of any width setting.

The conclusion is: by using `<input type=date>`, you accept whatever browser-dependent widgets browsers might use, and an attempt to control e.g. in its size may very well mess things up,

Comment: all elements should honor the CSS specified for them, should they not?. and it's not like I care about the look of the UI element while it's editing, but the statically displayed value when not editing.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="date" name="tanggal" style="width:231px">
```

Hope this works! 
It doesn't change anything except the width.

Answer (score 1):

Since most browsers aren't up  to speed with html5 yet. I would just use the date picker with jquery.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>


</body>
</html>
```

I've used it plenty and it works a treat. Makes more sense to present the calendar on click as well imo.

Here's the link as well:  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: This is a Chrome only application, so i am not worried about IE never being compliant. If there is no other solution to the actual problem, i will revisit this solution. +1 for an alternative though.

Comment: Thanks Austin, glad I could help out and take part in this discussion.  =]

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, correct. That's why my recommendation didn't get the green check. =]