# How to make input type date responsive

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have created a form which has 4 columns. 1 of the columns contain input type as date. When I am testing my form with diff. size browsers, I can see all fields are getting shrinked correctly but date box is not responsive. How to make date box responsive?
I have used

```
<div class="col-3"> 
    <div class="centerBlock">
        <input type="date" id="version_date" name="version_date" formControlName="a_0_loanNumber">
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: This is a duplicat question see awnsers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228135/responsive-date-from-date-to-css-layout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive date from date to css layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40228135/responsive-date-from-date-to-css-layout)

Comment: <input type=date> is interpreted by the browser. You are not supposed to style it, the browser does it.

Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860093/6927323